# Sed for windows

Tags: windows, sed, gnuwin32

I am attempting to use SED for the first time. To complicate matters, I am using it in Windows. I downloaded from [this source](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). Since I don't have installation privileges on my work machine, I created a folder in my profile for executables and added it to my `PATH`.

I am having issues trying to use SED for the first time.  It keeps failing with the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I have tried a few different samples from [this how to](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1), but I just can't get it. I found noone else is having this problem. What should I try? I have tried encapsulating it in quotes, double quotes, and back-quotes. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: What exactly are you running?

Comment: I would highly recommend cygwin, the windows shell is such a PITA for unix-like commands. However, if you are planning on sticking with the windows shell, the easiest way ive found to run sed or awk is by creating a script file and then calling the file with the -f flag. For example `sed -f some_sed_script.sed` or `awk -f some_awk_script.awk`

Comment: Can you paste exactly what you're giving to the windows shell?

Comment: I thought I did include my input. I wish i did, because now it works after I tried @RedGrittyBrick gave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C:\>sed sdf
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: Unterminated `s' command

C:\>echo aaa > f
C:\>sed -e "s/a/x/" < f
xaa
```

This is using `sed` from [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: This worked!. thank you.  Is is that because the `-e` parameter ?

Comment: Not sure what was wrong, removing the `-e ` parameter and the double `"` quotes, it still works

Answer (score 6):

Unlike the Unixes, the Windows command-line shell does not perform any word-splitting and does not strip away the quotes; the program just receives a single string containing the entire command line. This means that not all programs can follow the same quoting rules.

In this case, the GnuWin32 version of *sed* only supports one quoting style – `"` double quotes `"`. For example, in my tests the following works fine:

```
sed "s/foo/bar/"
```

You can also get `sed` from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), along with a more-complete Unix-like system: shells, editors, other tools. It will be easier if you use a Unix shell for learning, to avoid such syntax issues in the future.

Comment: beat my cygwin comment by seconds... :)

Comment: thanks. Does _CygWin_ offer a non install? I tried with `"` double quotes and still no joy.

Comment: @TheSavo just delete the directory. there are some registry entries related to cygwin mounts, but these can be safely ignored, only cygwin reads them

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate this is an old question however if you have [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) installed you can use a lot of unix features (sed /ssh / scp/ grep) in a Windows environment.